# Cookies lifetime and turning off PC

Tags: language-agnostic

When a PC is turned off, are all of the cookies destroyed or kept? In particular, this is with an ASP.NET/Sharepoint app.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cookies can persist past the uptime of the PC.  They're stored on disk according to the expiration time set by the website and optionally overridden by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking no. Cookies are kept until they expire (you can set the expiration date for an ASP.NET cookie by using the HttpCookie.Expires property).

But a user might have there browser setup to delete any cookies when they close the browser. So you can't really rely on cookies being deleted or not from a client's machine.